# RSA-OAEP Encrypt: OperationError on File upload but not strings using SubtleCrypto

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, subtlecrypto

I am trying to allow the client to upload a file, have the file be encrypted with RSA-OAEP using a public key provided by the server, then have the file be uploaded and completely readable by the server.
However, my current code gives me `OperationError: The operation failed for an operation-specific reason` (on Safari and Firefox). Here is my code:

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('change', async event => {
    if (event.target.files[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('load', async (event2) => {
            const res = await fetch("/key");
            const exported = await res.text();
            const key = await importRSAPublicKey(exported);
            const arrayBuffer = event2.target.result;
            console.log(arrayBuffer);
            const encrypted = await encryptRSA(key, arrayBuffer); // Fails here at the call to window.crypto.subtle.encrypt()
            console.log(encrypted);
            await fetch(`/upload`, {method: "POST", body: encrypted});
        });
        reader.addEventListener('error', () => {
            reject(new Error("There was an error reading the inserted file as text."));
        })
        /**
         * @type {File}
         */
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
});

async function importRSAPublicKey(key) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const imported = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
                "jwk",
                JSON.parse(atob(key)),
                {
                    name: "RSA-OAEP",
                    modulusLength: 4096,
                    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
                    hash: "SHA-256",
                },
                true,
                ["encrypt"]
            );
            return resolve(imported);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    })
}

async function encryptRSA(key, data) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {       
            const encryptedData = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
                { name: "RSA-OAEP" },
                key,
                data
            )
    
            const uintArray = new Uint8Array(encryptedData);
    
            const string = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uintArray);
    
            const base64Data = btoa(string);
    
            return resolve(base64Data);
        } catch (error) {
            return reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Interestingly, the same operation, when preformed either on text or via similar code for AES-GCM on the same file, works perfectly. Here is my (working) code for the plaintext application:

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('change', async event => {
    const res = await fetch("/key");
    const exported = await res.text();
    const key = await importRSAPublicKey(exported);
    const encrypted = await encryptRSA(key, new TextEncoder().encode("Test"));
    console.log(encrypted);
    await fetch(`/upload`, {method: "POST", body: encrypted});
});
// ... Helper functions from the previous codeblock unchanged
```

Why, since both times an ArrayBuffer is being passed into the function, does one work and the other not?

I would love it if someone could tell me a way I can encrypt these without using btoa() on the cleartext (which is a pain to convert back into actual binary from there).

UPDATE: The same issue occurs if I load the file using File.prototype.arrayBuffer() instead of reading it with a FileReader.

Comment: RSA is not  well suited for file encryption, as your data needs to be shorter than the key size (minus the data that is used for the OAEP padding). Is your file bigger than your key size ?

Comment: So, would a good solution be to encrypt the file using AES using a newly-generated key, then send the key encrypted with RSA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by [@Ebbe M. Pedersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196561/ebbe-m-pedersen), it was brought to my attention that my angle was all wrong. It is not possible to encrypt larger files using RSA, and instead my approach should be to encrypt the file using AES-GCM, then encrypt this AES key with RSA, before sending it.